# Regular expression to find substring bound by < >

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

What is the NSRegularExpression code to get a first occurrence of a substring bound by <> in a given string.

Example search string:

```
*01234:Q23WFA:10<HELLOWORLD>09AS:1019
```

Needed result: `HELLOWORLD`

Thanks.

Comment: `/<(.*?)>/s` ? Maybe that should work?

Comment: Does it need to be a regular expression? Get the first range of the `<` substring then get the first range of the `>` substring starting with the location of the `<`. This would be much more efficient than using regular expressions.

Comment: @rmaddy That is what I currently have, I thought NSRegularExpression would be faster.

Comment: General purpose regular expressions are rarely more efficient than specific purpose code.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks. If you can answer this question with the NSRegularExpression I will add my substring solution so others have something to choose from. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
NSString *string = @"*01234:Q23WFA:10<HELLOWORLD>09AS:1019";
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=<)(.*?)(?=>)"
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:&error];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:string
                                                options:0
                                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
    NSRange resultRange = [match range];
    NSString *substring = [string substringWithRange:resultRange];
    NSLog(@"Testing Indicator. Result is %@", substring);
```